# Splitting by delimiter in big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with IP's. I would like to create another columns with the subnet mask.
Is there a way to do it in big query? I need specifically to split by delimiter as below:

```
IP       Subnet 
1.2.3.4  1.2
1.2.4.5  1.2
1.2.6.7  1.2
2.3.4.6  2.3
2.3.7.8  2.3
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need specifically to split by delimiter

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.table` AS (
  select '1.2.3.4' col1 union all
  select '1.2.4.5' union all
  select '1.2.6.7' union all
  select '2.3.4.6' union all
  select '2.3.7.8' 
)
select col1, regexp_extract(col1, r'\d+.\d+') col2
from `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve the result by using `SUBSTR()` and `INSTR()`:

```
with mytable AS (
  select '1.2.3.4' IP union all
  select '1.2.4.5' IP union all
  select '1.2.6.7' IP union all
  select '2.3.4.6' IP union all
  select '2.3.7.8' IP 
)
select IP, 
       SUBSTR(IP, 1, INSTR(IP, '.', 1, 2)-1) Subnet 
  from mytable
```

> **INSTR**(source_value, search_value, position, occurrence)